# IndexAt with condition

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string like this:

```
arc boat arc ship arc ship ship arc boat arc
```

and I need to find the index of the first "arc" that follows a "boat".

What is the most efficient way to meet this condition in C#?

Comment: have you heard of regular expressions?

Comment: Do you mean "boat" needs to be the direct predecessor of "arc"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works if you mean 'immediately' after:

```
myString.IndexOf("boat arc") + 5;
```

Comment: I guess "immediately after" as in "immediately after 'boat' and one space character" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
str.IndexOf("arc", str.IndexOf("boat"));
```

Comment: depends if OP means "arc that *immediately* follows boat", or if there might be more text in between.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@".*?boat\s*?(?=arc)");
Match match = reg.Match("arc boat arc ship arc ship ship arc boat arc");

int index = match.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regular Expression:

```
^(arc\sboat)
```